# Make PHP Get Request Without Question Mark

Tags: php, post, get

I need some help. Whenever I am making a PHP get request, say for name, how would I change  this:
http://website.com/page?name=Something

to this:
http://website.com/page/Something

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you need to use something like apache mod_rewrite to rewrite the url to script.  search for that and you will find a ton of examples

Comment: It is called URL rewriting.  Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php).

Comment: @Doon You don’t necessarily need URL rewriting techniques, something like Apache’s *MultiViews* and *path info* would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Use htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/ page?name=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to be able to **route** requests. It depends on how your application receive requests

If you're using apache with mod_php, the routing corresponds to your filesystem (path in the request → path of the file). This is a very bad form of routing, and confuses a lot of beginners, because you have basically no power on how the requests are handled. Your best solution is to use [Apache URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html), which will allow you to transform /page/something into /page?name=something so that it can be handled properly by mod_php.

If you have more control on your httpd, you should try some PHP routing libraries like https://github.com/chriso/klein.php or http://zaphpa.org/ that will give you a better control on how your requests are dispatched.